# beautifulsoup find method returns: TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an html file, i try to use find method to return fetched data from this file , here is my code

Update: I removed .text after find() method , and it returns None! but i'm sure that the value is in file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r= open('D:\IT\programming\Python\Data-science\WebScraping\ParseFiles\\test.html', encoding="utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser').text
data = soup.find('span', class_='a-column a-span4 a-text-right a-span-last')
print(data)
```

It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/web_scraping/get_book_price.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = soup.find('span', class_='a-column a-span4 a-text-right a-span-last').span
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: You aren't calling BeautifulSoup's `.find()`, you're calling it on an ordinary string object (the `.text` attribute from your BeautifulSoup object).

Comment: remove `.text` use only `soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')`

Comment: Try this: `data = soup.find('span', {'class': 'a-column a-span4 a-text-right a-span-last'})`

Comment: Do you not want a single \ at the end of the file address as well as opposed to the current \\

Comment: I removed .text and the code returns none !

Comment: @QHarr  it works fine